# Android + Phonegap + Admob

Tags: android, cordova, admob

As the title suggests I am trying to create an Android app using Phonegap and then trying to insert Admob into it.

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html) provided by Adobe and it is working fine. After this when I use [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) provided by Google I run into problems. 
According to the Google tutorial, I have to change the activity class, below is the original and the second block of code is the altered code. There doesn't seem to be any errors preventing it from compiling. It's just when I try and run it using the Android emulator I get an error stating "Unfortunately MyFirstPhonegapPlugin has stopped"

Note, using the Google tutorial, there are two ways of implementing the code, using just the class below and using a mixture of XML and the class below. I tried the other way and due to getting errors which doesn't let me compile, I've gone for this way.

```
package com.tricedesigns;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyFirstPhoneGapPluginActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Adjusted code:

```
 package com.tricedesigns;

    import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
    import android.os.Bundle; 
    import com.google.ads.*;


    public class MyFirstPhoneGapPluginActivity extends DroidGap {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
            // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
            AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
          }
        }
```

I am using Phonegap 1.6.1 and the most up to date SDK for Android and Admob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Phonegap is implemented, it pretty much hides all the details about Android and lets you basically implement a mobile web app as a native app. If you care to implement Android natively, I'd recommend reading the [Hello World](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) tutorial. The code you have here is crashing on `AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);` because you don't have a layout file with an AdView element with id `adView`.

If you're more interested in the mobile web part of it and plan to continue sticking with Phonegap, your best bet is to try [this plugin](https://github.com/rajpara11/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/AdMobPlugin) which lets you make JavaScript calls using the Phonegap framework, and the plugin performs all of the underlying Android calls necessary to get ads.

Comment: Thanks for that Eric, exactly what I’m after. Just trying to get through it now and there’s a couple of things tripping me up. Where is the “AdMob Cordova plugin jar”, it states this needs to be added, but I can’t see it. Is this “AdMobPlugin.java” which is supplied and doesn’t appear to be used? Little confused here as it is not a jar file.

Also, I can’t find cordova.xml. I have download the most up to date PhoneGap and it only has a config.xml file. I have created a plugin.xml file.

And last but not least, when I am calling the plugin, where do I put createBannerView and requestAd? 
Cheers

Comment: Yeah, the "AdMob Cordova plugin jar" is just the AdMobPlugin.Java file.  Looks like Cordova.xml  and Plugins.xml were recently combined into the single config.xml file, so you'd only include the config.xml file, and add the <plugin> entry to config.xml. As for using the plugin, it's just plain old JavaScript.  I believe phonegap uses the deviceReady listener to tell you it's ready, so you could add `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    createBannerView(...);
     }, true);`  Then, if createBannerView succeeeds, you can call `loadAd`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob) a fully functional project of what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

old version phonegap not support extenal jar lib.
but now phonegap add some new feathers.
use phonegap builder ,add config
add some config

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.plugin" version="1.0.0" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
```

so not need any java code any more.
just need some js code.

```
admob.initAdmob("admob banner ID","admob interstitial ID");
admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,admob.Position.TOP_APP);
```

this will create and show a admob banner at top of your app.